# Possible to maintain bind w/ delegate after removal then recreation of element

Tags: jquery

I am creating bindings to all Anchors under LI in a UL. (I am using Delegate because I am at 1.6 jQuery version at work). Anyways, for a reason I remove a texts anchor. Then reapply it at a later time.

In short, is there a way to bind an Anchor tag with delegate, remove anchor tag because of some condition. Reapply anchor (via wrap), and then get back that binding?

Just so I am clear, I am using "delegate" - but once I unwrap the anchor tag, the binding is lost of good - even when I re-wrap it. ala.

```
jQuery(pc).delegate("li > a",'click', function(){
    showit(jQuery(this).closest('li').index());
    pc.find("li:not(:has(a))").wrap('<a href="#">'); <-- this is when I add it lateron
    jQuery(this).replaceWith(jQuery(this).text()); <-- this is when I remove it.
});
```

**EDIT::: Perhaps this could help someone in the future. DELEGATE does work as intended. If you review my code, you will see that I wrap the "LI" , NOT the text in the li. That is why the event did NOT retain its bind. When I wrapped the text of the LI with an anchor, bingo - it worked.
I apologize for sidetracking peoples time. So, the solution is "wrapInner", not "wrap" in this case.**

Comment: Can you explain what it is you're after more clearly with HTML and the JavaScript you tried but didn't work?

Comment: Isn't that exactly what `.delegate()` is for?

Comment: that is what I thought. It is able to get the bind on elements created now or in the future.

Comment: What does the `pc` variable contain?

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean something like this  ?

```
   if(new Date().getTime() % 2 == 0) 
     {
        $("body").on('click','ul>li a', doWork);
     }
     else
    {
        $("body").off('click');
    }

     //...
     //...
     // later , ReBind the event ...    


function doWork()
{
        alert('mod2');
}
```

[jsbin](http://jsbin.com/uvakit/2/edit)

Comment: I can't use on/off. I don't have the upgraded jQuery version. I am stuck at 1.6 for the time being.

Comment: just change "on" to "delegate" ( sorry for not paying attention)

Answer (score 1):

For more information, please see the "delegate" area of jQuery's `on`:
http://api.jquery.com/on/

If you apply your binding to the document, it should handle your adding and removing anchors:

```
jQuery(document).on('click', 'ul li a', function(event){
  // Check event here
  // Do something here
});
```

Comment: can't use 'on'. Dont have that version of jQuery - am stuck with 1.6

Comment: @jamesemanon: Oops, I missed that detail.  As Royi and Juhana said, you should use "delegate" instead of "on".

Comment: That is the issue. I "am" using Delegate, but once I unwrap the Anchor tag..... and re-wrap it later on, that binding is not longer available. Any ideas?